# How do identical python installation scripts have different behavior on different Ubuntus?

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, package-management, python, 18.04

I've traced [a bug in the numba project](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/3027) to differences in Ubuntu installations. I've tried reproducing the bug in various AWS ubuntu AMIs, and the bug only manifests in Ubuntu 14.04. So my question is, how is it that the same set of installation commands come to have different behavior on different ubuntu installations? Is it possible that different versions of python packages are installed on each version of ubuntu, and is there are way to check for differences?

I ran my test on:

```
Ubuntu 18.04 LTS [PASS] (ami-e3293383)
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS [PASS] (ami-43243a23)
Ubuntu 14.04 LTS [FAIL] (ami-e4293384)
```

The test is:

```
cat > issue3027.py  # Test program

import sys
import numba


@numba.njit
def f0(a,b):
  return a+b


@numba.njit
def f1(begin1, end1, begin2, end2):
  if begin1 > begin2: return f1(begin2, end2, begin1, end1)
  return end1 + 1 >= begin2

sys.api_version, sys.stdout = 12345, None


print>>sys.stderr, sys.api_version, sys.stdout  # 12345, None
f0(0,1)      # Does not reassign stdout
print>>sys.stderr, sys.api_version, sys.stdout  # 12345, None
f1(0,1,2,3)  # Reassigned stdout
print>>sys.stderr, sys.api_version, sys.stdout  # 12345, file object


assert sys.api_version == 12345  # Pass. From which we can infer reload was not called
assert sys.stdout is None  # Fail. sys.stdout was assigned and not reset.
```

Then:

```
   sudo apt-get update --yes
   sudo apt-get install  --yes python2.7 python-pip python-dev
   sudo pip install pip==9.0.1
   sudo pip install 'enum34==1.1.6' 'funcsigs==1.0.2' 'llvmlite==0.23.2' 'numba==0.38.1' 'numpy==1.14.5' 'singledispatch==3.4.0.3' 'six==1.11.0'
   python2.7 issue3027.py  # Pass/Fail?
```

Comment: Packages installed via pip are not ubuntu packages.

Comment: Sure -- but AFAIK, pip doesn't (shouldn't) behave differently depending on the Ubuntu installation. The variation here is not because of different ubuntu versions.

Comment: Sorry for the slightly impolite comment. I just don't think this is an easy thing to debug. E. g. numpy is a huge package and I wouldn't wonder if it does distro specific things.

Comment: I've been using numpy for quite some time in 14.04 - I haven't seen it assign to sys.stdout (which is easy to spot since it breaks PyCharm's unittest runner).